# filter with includes inside on() ngrx reducer

Tags: angular, typescript, filter, ngrx, mutation

I have text from an input going inside my action to that fires this reducer. I want my state array to update on every input. Right now what happens is the state is filtered and remains filtered, even when there is no text in the input. Can I make the array more dynamic so it doesn't mutate the state permanently and changes depending what is typed in? Like I've seen before when I'm subscribed to an observable.

Ngrx Reducer:

```
export const dataReducer = createReducer<Songs[]>(
on(filterTable, (state, action) => {
        return state.filter((item) => item.artist.toLowerCase().includes(action.text.toLowerCase()));
    })
);
```

Action:

```
export const filterTable = createAction("[DATABASE] filterTable", props<{ text: string; field: string }>());
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your state have an allItems and filteredItems. Only save the result to filteredItems. You could do this in a selector too, but for brevity I’ll edit your existing code.

```
 export const dataReducer = createReducer<Songs[]>(
   on(filterTable, (state, action) => {
      let _state = Object.assign({}, state);
      _state.filteredItems = state.allItems.filter((item) =>       
          item.artist.toLowerCase().includes(
            action.text.toLowerCase()));
       })
      return _state;
  );
```